# Is BufferedReader.readLine method non-blocking

Tags: java, project-reactor, java-nio

[image]

I was using Java NIO Files.lines method but i was curious to know the code so dig little bit further then i see some FileChannel of nio package.
my digging took me to buffered reader it seems like there nio is using io which is supposed to be blocking.

I was trying to read file for my webflux project reactor code but it seems like it could have some blocking in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedReader.readLine()` is a blocking method. Did you think that all java.nio methods were non-blocking? Only some are non-blocking, i.e. just those that are explicitly documented as being non-blocking. All the others are blocking. In particular, you ask about `Files.lines`. That returns a `Stream` of lines. It uses the blocking method `readLine()` internally, but it doesn't read all the lines in the file when you call it. It only reads each line when you make a terminal operation on the returned Stream.

Comment: Seems Java didnt document each method as Blocking or not. \
But for the `java.io.BufferedReader.read(char[], int, int)`. They stated a bit about it. :: \
""" \
> The `ready` method of the underlying stream returns `false`, indicating that further input requests would block. \
> \
> https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read(char[],int,int) \
""" \
(I think this behavior corresponds to how Pipe in C works.)